# What caused the changes in Hell mentioned in Hellraiser IV?

Tags: hellraiser

In Hellraiser IV Bloodlines, we see that several hundred years ago, Hell and its denizens were the traditional demon types. When the demon and Pinhead meet, he explains that Hell has changed since she left. Clearly, Hell has become a place of extreme pain and pleasure mixed together etc. Are there any indications anywhere for what caused this change? It appears to be significant enough that Pinhead is even able to suborn the demon and convert her into a cenobite under his thrall.